# How to update existing values and save new values in parse.com

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using parse app in my project, I seen the documents from parse and they mentioned for save and update separately . I want to do like sql.If the row is present in table it should update the values and if not it should save the values newly. How can i do that in single function.
Here is my code

```
Parse.initialize(parseId.APPLICAITONID, parseId.JAVASCRIPTID);
    var locationMobileMsgs = Parse.Object.extend("LocationMobileMessages");
    var locationMsgs = new Parse.Query(locationMobileMsgs);
    locationMsgs.equalTo('LocationId',123);
    locationMsgs.find({success:function(data){          
       // if the values are not there i need to use query.save here.
       // otherwise i can do below
        data.set('BodyText',msgObj.mobileTextarea);
        data.set('HeaderText',msgObj.mobileHeadline);
        data.set('LocationId',msgObj.locationId);
        data.save();
        console.log('saved');

        },error:function(errData){
            console.log('error occured');
            res.json(errData);
        }
    });
```

Comment: If that helps your search, I think people use to call that _upsert_. I found [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/how-can-i-upsert) and [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/upsert-support) about upsert in Parse.com.

Comment: What i want is like using javascript i should find the records if no save if yes update

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify use the `if` statement:

```
locationMsgs.find({success: function (results) {
    // if the values are not there i need to use query.save here.
    if (results.length === 0) {
        //insert...
    } else {
        // otherwise i can do below
        results.forEach(function (data) {
            data.set('BodyText', msgObj.mobileTextarea);
            data.set('HeaderText', msgObj.mobileHeadline);
            data.set('LocationId', msgObj.locationId);
            data.save();
        });
    }, error: //...
```

Or if you have at most one object to update:

```
locationMsgs.first({success: function (data) {
    // if the values are not there i need to use query.save here.
    if (!data) {
        //insert...
    } else {
        // otherwise i can do below
        data.set('BodyText', msgObj.mobileTextarea);
        data.set('HeaderText', msgObj.mobileHeadline);
        data.set('LocationId', msgObj.locationId);
        data.save();
    }, error: //...
```

Comment: Now am using like your code only.I would like to optimize the code.
you mentioned //insert . there we need to call the parse again like locationMessages.save({}). I want to do in  one service call.Is that possible.